# The name of the ubuntu 4 screens split window

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, 16.04, extension, split

In my university's linux, there is in the dock a button that when we click on it, we can move the screen to either top right/bottom left/bottom right, and the actual screen is in the top left of this split screen. It was extremely useful cuz I was able to put for example a terminal in a screen view, and other stuff in other views. But I can't remember at all it's name...

This image explains what I'm trying to have and what do I mean by split screen into 4. Can you guys tell me what is this called and how to do it in  ubuntu 16.04 ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the workspace switcher, you can enable it in the system settings >> appearance >> behavior.

[image]

Then you can install unity-tweak-tool to configure them in workspace settings

`sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool`

[image]

[image]

Comment: offtopic sorry Mark but how did you get your ubuntu window bars to look so good?

Comment: You mean the theme? It is this one https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1167049/  and I used unity-tweak-tool from the repos to move the controls to the left. I beleve it is the arc darker version. @anon58192932

Comment: 4 years later I still come to check the name when I forget :P thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to Mark's post, to launch unity tweak tool:

```
unity-tweak-tool
```

You might encounter issues, or not be able to launch Unity Tweak tool:

```
Error: schema com.canonical.Unity.ApplicationsLens not installed
```

You can try to install dependencies first:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files
```