# how to split window in ubuntu 20.04 into four parts

Tags: 20.04, .desktop, split

I want to split the window of my ubuntu 20.04 desktop into four parts. I looked for possible approach as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911044/the-name-of-the-ubuntu-4-screens-split-window). First of all, I am not able to get the options as shown in the settings/appearance section of the above question.
secondly, the unity-tweak-tool is not accessible through the terminal(maybe I don't know the proper way to access it).

Any help is appreciated.
NOTE: I could ask in the same thread of that question, but the reputation is restricting me from doing that.

Comment: Ubuntu has both product that use the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 20) and products that use the *year.month* format (eg. 20.04) - but they are different products/systems.  You've used both?  Which are you using?  Ubuntu Core 20 is a server system, desktop systems however are Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for example; and not a 20 system.  Please clarify your release.

Comment: @guiverc, I am using ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: @Mark ,Using of corner or window key+arrow keys isn't working. I'm a newbie to linux, so i don't understand whats XFCE

Comment: Please correct your question; 20 is not 20.04 (20 is used for *snap* only releases; 20.04 being the *year.month* format for *deb* based releases which are more powerful/flexible)

Comment: Is this any use? https://askubuntu.com/questions/190092/how-to-stack-open-windows-side-by-side - it can be done in quarters as well as halves

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu 22.04 you will actually apply gnome-tweaks instead of gnome-tweak-tool:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all install gnome-shell-extensions

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

then install the gnome-tweak-tool

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

This tweak-tool can come much handy than you think, we can easily manipulate the window size, and move it/relocate it to our need.

The second method is to go to gnome website. Theirin, search for gTile, but having installed "gnome-shell-extensions" is a prerequisite. You can also download>>install the browser version(available on the website itself) to let your browser support the tweaks done by the gnome extension.

The below is a great source to understand how gnome-shell and its extensions work.
https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/

Comment: this does not answer the question at all

Comment: @DmitryOrlov This method let's you activate the toolkit needed to split screen